# How to delegate an attribute request up the MRO chain from a descriptor

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, attributes

If I have a parent class and a child class, I get the following behavior in Python when asking for attributes:

```
class Parent():
    i = 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, j = 2):
        self.j = j

ch = Child()
print(ch.i, ch.j) # 1 2
```

The request for the `i` and `j` attributes go up the MRO chain as expected; `i` is found in the parent class attributes, `j` is found in the instance attributes.

Now, if I add a generic descriptor and replace the `j` attribute in `Child`, this happens:

```
class _Attr():
    def __init__(self, attr_name):
        self.attr_name = '_' + attr_name
    def __get__(self, instance, klass):
        return getattr(instance, self.attr_name)

class Child(Parent):
    j = _Attr('j')
    def __init__(self, j = 2):
        self._j = j

ch = Child()
print(ch.i, ch.j) # 1 2
```

So far, so good.

However, using the above descriptor, if we do something like this:

```
class Child(Parent):
    j = _Attr('j')
    i = _Attr('i')
    def __init__(self, j = 2):
        self._j = j

ch = Child()
print(ch.i, ch.j) # AttributeError: 'Ch" object has no attribute '_i'
```

This error occurs because of this failed attribute lookup:

```
return getattr(ch, '_i')
```

What I want is for the descriptor to "fail silently" and for the attribute lookup to continue up the MRO chain. I'm unsure how to do this.

I tried this:

```
class _Attr():
    def __init__(self, attr_name):
        self.attr_name = '_' + attr_name
    def __get__(self, instance, klass):
        result = getattr(instance, self.attr_name, None)
        if result == None:
            return NotImplemented
        else:
            return result
```

But that does not do the trick. How can I get the behavior I want? I have a feeling I need to use `super()` somehow in this case, but I don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1. you need to store the reference to the actual attribute name in the `_Attr`, so that you can use that in the parent lookup.
2. during the lookup, you can delegate the attribute fetching work to the `Parent` class, with `super(klass, instance)`

So your `_Attr` would look like this

```
class _Attr():

    def __init__(self, attr_name):
        self._original_name = attr_name
        self.attr_name = '_' + attr_name

    def __get__(self, instance, klass):
        if hasattr(instance, self.attr_name):
            return getattr(instance, self.attr_name)
        return getattr(super(klass, instance), self._original_name)
```

Comment: haven't tested yet, but this won't result in a circular reference...? if not, why doesn't `getattr(super(klass, instance), self._original_name)` put me right back into the descriptor again...?

Comment: confirmed that it works! now i need to figure out WHY it works... how does `super()` know we have already looked in the descriptor?

Comment: @RickTeachey When we do `super(klass, instance)`, it creates a Proxy object, which will help us access the parent class. So, when we do `getattr(super(klass, instance)...` it will directly hit the `Parent` for `self._original_name`. Remember, here, `klass` is `Child` and `instance` is `ch`.

Comment: that's helpful. will probably take me a while to digest what that all means. i guess i need to go read up on super a bit more.

Comment: @RickTeachey You might want to start with [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) and [this](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: yeah i've read both of those before, multiple times. jsut hasn't sunk in yet i guess. i usually give it half a day or so before accepting in case other people have better ideas. i will eventually though.

Comment: @RickTeachey Well, it took me sometime before understanding the basics of `super`. The MRO in Python 3.x is still a gray area to me :(

Comment: Aha!!! ["The search order is same as that used by `getattr()` except that the `type` itself is skipped."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) That pretty much explains everything.

Comment: @RickTeachey Yup, it is same as `getattr`. You can confirm that like this `return super(klass, instance).i`

Comment: Is there any reason not to do `try:` `return getattr(instance, self.attr_name)` `except AttributeError:` `return getattr(super(klass, instance), self._original_name)`? That way it follows EAFP.

Comment: @RickTeachey Well, if you think most of the times your code will not fail, then you can go with this approach. After all, Python encourages [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can take care of setting _i in the init method as follows.

```
class Child(P):
    j = _Attr('j')
    i = _Attr('i')
    def __init__(self, j = 2):
        self._j = j
        self._i = P.i

ch = Child()
print(ch._i, ch._j)
```

Comment: interesting way of doing it i hadn't thought of. i'm more focused on getting it working by tweaking the descriptor in this particular situation though.